# How do i 'get' help string from commons cli instead of 'print'

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I know, the below code will generate and print the help text to the console

```
 HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
 formatter.printHelp("myapp", header, options, footer, true);
```

but how do i get the help text as a `String` object. I am expecting something like

```
formatter.getHelp("myapp", header, options, footer, true);
```

Is there any method hidden in the `CLI` API ? or Is there any way to get the help text instead of printing it to the console.

Comment: Thanks for asking so we don't have to :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following

```
    HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();

    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);

    formatter.printHelp(pw, 80, "myapp", "test-header", opts,
            formatter.getLeftPadding(), formatter.getDescPadding(), "test-footer", true);
    pw.flush();

    System.out.println("Had usage: " + out.toString());
```

See the [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/HelpFormatter.html#printHelp(java.io.PrintWriter,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.cli.Options,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) for details.